# como convertir anyObject a Int32

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Necesito convertir un `anyObject` que viene de un `JSON` de un servicio web a `Int32` he intentado de muchas maneras pero ninguna me resulta. La última que tengo es esta:

```
let puntos = "\(objeto["CATPUNTOS"])" as? NSString
cat.catPuntos = Int32(String(puntos!))!
```

en donde `cat` es un objeto, al ejecutarlo me sale este error en la segunda línea

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value" EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code: exc_1386_invop)

Comment: la segunda linea es esta:   cat.catPuntos = Int32(String(puntos!))!

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el JSON para verlo? O si es posible, el trozo en cuestión...

Comment: gracias ya encontre como jejejeje   cat.catPuntos = puntos!.intValue

Comment: Aunque te haya funcionado, no es la mejor forma. Si pega el JSON te contesto la pregunta con detalles de como hacerlo de forma correcta.

Comment: el json vienen  de un servicio web yo no lo creo mira hay te envio el codigo:

Answer (score 0):

//SINCRONIA DE CATEGORIAS
            let dir = Helpers.REQUESTAPIURL + "/sincronizarCategoriasApp?idUsuario=(idUsuario!)"
            let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:dir)!
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL : url)
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler : {data , response , error ->   Void in
                if (error != nil){
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }
                else{
                    let nsdata: NSData = NSData(data: data!)

```
                if(nsdata != ""){

                    do{
                        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(nsdata, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                        let arregloJsonList = json["categorias"] as? NSArray

                        if let nsArrayJsonList = arregloJsonList {
                            nsArrayJsonList.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({objeto, index, stop in

                                var datos: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
                                self.idCat = "\(objeto["catId"])" as? NSString
                                datos = ModeloBD.getInstance().findCategoriaByExternalId(String(self.idCat!))
                                var cat:CategoriaData = CategoriaData()
                                if datos.count > 0{
                                    cat = datos.objectAtIndex(0) as! CategoriaData
                                }
                                if cat.id == 0{
                                    if objeto["catOperacion"] as? String == "I"{
                                       print("aqui: \(objeto["CATNOMBRE"] as! String)")
                                        cat.externalId = Int32(self.idCat! as String)!
                                        cat.catNombre = objeto["CATNOMBRE"] as! String
                                        cat.catPuntos = ("\(objeto["CATPUNTOS"])" as? NSString)!.intValue
                                        cat.catEstado = ("\(objeto["CATESTADO"])" as? NSString)!.intValue
                                        cat.catVersion = ("\(objeto["CATVERSION"])" as? NSString)!.intValue
                                        cat.catOperacion = String(objeto["CATOPERACION"])

                                        ModeloBD.getInstance().registrarCategoria(cat)
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    if cat.catVersion < objeto["catVersion"] as? Int32{
                                        if objeto["catOperacion"] as? String == "U"{
                                            ModeloBD.getInstance().updateCategoria(cat)
                                        }
                                        else if objeto["catOperacion"] as? String == "D"{
                                             ModeloBD.getInstance().removeCategoria(String(self.idCat))
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            })
                        }

                    }catch{
                        self.msn = "Error al serealizar JSON"

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.mostrarAlert()
                        }

                    }

                }
                else{
                    self.msn = "Error, al sincronizar"

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.mostrarAlert()
                    }

                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
```

Comment: Sigo insistiendo, sin el JSON no puedo explicártelo bien. Haces varias conversiones innecesarias y propensas a errores.

Answer (score 0):

Debes asegurar que el "Objecto" que tienes como AnyObject sea una estructura de datos para que puedas pedir el valor de la llave "CATPUNTOS" y a ese String convertirlo a Numero.

```
if let obj = objeto as? [NSObject: AnyObject] {

    if let puntos = obj["CATPUNTOS"] as? String {

        cat.catPuntos = Int32(puntos) ?? 0
    }else{
        cat.catPuntos = 0;
    }
}
```

Tambien puedes usar https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON para ahorrarte algunas validaciones